# How can I stop Chrome from showing me the potentially dangerous message?

Tags: google-chrome

When I download files from a website (that I trust, I've uploaded the content) I get the message: " is not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous." I've searched around but every solution is for making the file safer, ie getting Google to review it or signing it etc.

I don't really care about that as no one else will be downloading it as it's a private site. **Is there a way that I can configure Chrome to stop showing me these messages** (for certain sites, or all sites, doesn't matter).

It's annoying having to click 'keep' every time. I just want Chrome to shut up and trust my superior judgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to chrome, setting, show advanced settings, privacy then uncheck "protect you and your device from dangerous sites" then it should stop giving warning about websites.